# How to set default download directory of any browser in php, jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

in php technology, i am trying to change the default download directory of any browser.

Comment: Hi, you can accept the answer by ticking the check icon beside the answer. If you find a post helpful, you can click the upvote icon (up icon) beside the answer score. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The default download direction/location of a browser is configurable from the client side by the user. PHP scripts resides and executes on the server side.

For Mozilla:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/959747

For Google Chrome:

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95574?hl=en

For Internet Explorer

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/112232-internet-explorer-change-default-download-location.html

For Safari:

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-change-safaris-default-file-download-locati.html

Comment: @RaviMane, unfortunately no. The download location of a file should be configured by the user and not by website providers due to security issues.

Comment: @RaviMane, putting an up-vote is enough! No need to thank me lol :) Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in [RFC 2182 section 2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2183#section-2.3). It is impossible because of security.

> The receiving MUA SHOULD NOT respect any directory path information
> that may seem to be present in the filename parameter.

You can only change suggested name of file that is being downloaded.